# Take the mean of a columns in csv and create a new row with the information

Tags: r, row, rstudio, addition, mean

I am pretty new to R but liked all of the help that was available. The problem I am encountering, is that there have been so many updates since a lot of videos and help sites have been made that the code is no longer valid.

I have a csv of immunization percentages and I want to find the mean of each column of data. If there is a way to add this value as the last row of data that would be ideal but not necessary. I have tried several different types of mean functions but I continue to get error messages.

I have tried the following codes. My file is called Measles1 and the columns are Y followed by the year. I took put the error codes specific to the lines but wanted to show what I have tried for reference. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
> colMeans(Measles1$Y2017)

> colMeans(Measles1)

> mean(Measles1$Y2017)

> mean(Measles1$Y2017, na.rm = TRUE)

> colMeans(Measles1$Y2017, na.rm = TRUE)

> Means <- colMeans(as.numeric(as.character(Measles1)))

> results.mean <- mean(Measles1)

> results.mean <- mean(Measles1,na.rm = TRUE)

> mean(Measles1[2:39])
```

I am sure that I am just missing something very simple. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try `new_Measles <- rbind(Measles1, colMeans(Measles1))`

Answer (score 0):

It would give us a better idea if you could provide a representative sample. You need to make sure that all columns are numeric in order to compute their means at once. One way to check this would be `str(your_data_frame)`.

Using the built-in `mtcars` dataset:

```
# na.rm argument is optional depending on your data
mtcars[nrow(mtcars) + 1, ] <- colMeans(mtcars, na.rm = T)
```

@Ronak Shah's recommendation works well, too:

```
mtcars <- rbind(mtcars, colMeans(mtcars, na.rm = T))
```

Comment: you were correct the data was not being stored as numeric. I fixed that and tried to use the code and realized the first column are the country names instead of being the titles of the rows. Once I fixed all of this the code worked perfect.

Answer (score 0):

This code will provide you option of finding grand total or mean by column values

```
d1 <- data_frame(
  name = c("jim", "john", "jim", "john"),
  `2012` = c(57, 58, 47, 57),
  `2013` = c(14, 3, 3, 90))

library(tidyverse)

d1 <-bind_rows(d1,
          d1 %>% 
            group_by(name) %>% 
            summarise_all(funs(mean)) %>%
            mutate(name = paste0(name, '_total')))
```